# Capture image from webcam without skipping frames everytime?

Tags: fswebcam

To capture an image that is not all black or saturated, I am currently using:

fswebcam -S 30 image.jpg

My application is a little delay sensitive and skipping around 30 frames every time to get a good image to process makes it difficult. I know capturing a frame from a running video sequence could solve this but I was wondering if there is a way to put the camera on standby or something similar to avoid having it to readjust to ambient brightness every time? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Most webcams will reinitialize after doing an operation (e.g. taking a picture). You can also observe this behavior on most mobile phones.

Best move would be to capture frames from a live video sequence, or look for a camera that won't reinitialize every after operation.

Alternatively, you can try tinkering with the `fswebcam`'s `--set` switch. Refer to the [man page](http://www.unix.com/man-page/debian/1/fswebcam/) for possible configuration options.